Can vector layers using memory data provider render QgsPalLayerSettings label?
I have a memory vector layer created from a GeoJSON feature:
    feature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": data,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": coords
            },
            "id": dev_id
        }

And it's rendered by a QgsSingleSymbolRenderer. Now I need to put a label near the rendered symbol, and I use label settings created from QgsPalLayerSettings.
Problem is when I create the vector layer using a "ogr" type data provider everything works fine. The label rendered as expected. But when using "memory" type data provider there is nothing rendered. The text label handling part is as below:

# Create label settings
label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label_settings.fieldName = field_name
label_settings.drawLabels = True
label_settings.enabled = True

# Create text format for labels
font = label_cfg["font"]
size = label_cfg["size"]
text_format = QgsTextFormat()
text_format.setFont(QFont(font, size))
fg_color = label_cfg["fg_color"]
bg_color = label_cfg["bg_color"]
text_format.setColor(QColor(fg_color))
text_format.setSize(size)
background_color = QgsTextBackgroundSettings()
background_color.setFillColor(QColor(bg_color))
background_color.setEnabled(label_cfg["bg_enabled"])
text_format.setBackground(background_color)

# Set the text format to label settings
label_settings.setFormat(text_format)
# Set label placement
label_settings.yOffset = label_cfg["y_offset"]  
fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField("ball_name", QVariant.String))
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(fields)
layer.updateFields()
label_settings.fieldName = "ball_name"

# Create and set the labeling object
labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings)
layer.setLabeling(labels)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)


Does a GeoJSON based vector layer with "memory" type data provider require extra steps to render simple label than same layer with "ogr" data provider?
I'm using PyQGIS binding with QGIS 3.32.3 version SDK. I've searched a lot of examples online and it appears no significant difference exist between different data provider types.
